# Microsoft Translator Api in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-translator

I developed an asp.net web application which translate the text into the multiple language through the Microsoft Translator API.

I have also downloaded the `TranslatorContainer.cs` file in my project. After selecting the language the following exception coming:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException' occurred in System.Data.Services.Client.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Following is my code:

```
protected void DDLLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri TranslatorUri = new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate", UriKind.Absolute);
        TranslatorContainer TC = new TranslatorContainer(TranslatorUri);
        string Key = " nQbC5yt6BtCCvXRXQIW11mR1gzkxi8n1K1cTl9b/uvM";
        TC.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Key, Key);
        Translation TranslatedText = TC.Translate(TxtTranslate.Text, DDLLanguage.SelectedValue,"en").Single();
        LblTranslatedText.Text = TranslatedText.Text;
    }
```

My Event Viewer Shows:

```
Windows cannot load classes registry file. DETAIL - The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: When you encounter an exception that confuses you, surround the bad code with a `try/catch` block and call `ToString()` on the exception.  The result is the full details of the exception, any inner exceptions, and the call stack.  This information will either be your answer, or if you [edit] and add this to your question, will help others decode your problem.

Comment: @Will My InnerException is: ""The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported\r\n""